# Unexpected method call in EasyMock

Tags: java, easymock

I have some piece of code:

```
if (wfStepExDetails.isPresent()) {
   this.postInterruptActionsExecutor.takeActionAfterWFInterrupted(wfStepExDetails.get(), this.pAccId, interrupts, this.workflowStepDefinition);
}
```

Inside test class:

```
@Test
public void testHandlePostInterruptActions() {
postInterruptActionsExecutor.takeActionAfterWFInterrupted(getWfStepExecutionDetails().get(0), pAccId, interrupt, wfStep);
    expectLastCall();
    replay(postInterruptActionsExecutor);
    orchestrator.handlePostInterruptActions(interrupt);
    EasyMock.verify(postInterruptActionsExecutor, orcDepProvider, pwaDAO, pdh);
}
```

Test is failing due to mismatch argument:

```
[junit]   Unexpected method call PostInterruptActionsExecutor.takeActionAfterWFInterrupted(WorkflowStepExecutionDetails(wfStepName=null, wfId=4c46f286-c368-49e7-a7db-30c39d72d1b8, planId=null, resultBranch=null, wfStepStatus=null, creationTime=null, workflowStepRequirements=null, attemptCount=null, parentWfStepId=null, wfStepType=null, wfStepDependencyResponseId=null), "81bd1b7e-7433-4116-bf46-52318b493e93", [com.amazon.verificationorchestration.plan.Interrupt@9e781b8e], com.amazon.verificationorchestration.plan.InitiateTokenVerificationWorkflowStep@860a7ec9):
[junit]   PostInterruptActionsExecutor.takeActionAfterWFInterrupted(WorkflowStepExecutionDetails(wfStepName=null, wfId=4c46f286-c368-49e7-a7db-30c39d72d1b8, planId=null, resultBranch=null, wfStepStatus=null, creationTime=null, workflowStepRequirements=null, attemptCount=null, parentWfStepId=null, wfStepType=null, wfStepDependencyResponseId=null), "81bd1b7e-7433-4116-bf46-52318b493e93", [com.amazon.verificationorchestration.plan.Interrupt@9e781b8e], com.amazon.verificationorchestration.plan.InitiateTokenVerificationWorkflowStep@860a7ec9): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

Even though expected and actual call contains same argument test is still failing. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: what your error message is actually saying, is that through your mocking, you indicate that you expect that specific call, with those params, but that call has not actually been made during the test.

Comment: It is actually the opposite. An unexpected call was made.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a slightly old version of EasyMock otherwise the message would be much clearer. Which version is it?

EasyMock is using `eq()` as the default matcher. Here I suspect that the `toString()` for `WorkflowStepExecutionDetails` make them look identical but `Object.equals` is probably not overridden. And since they are two different instances, they are not equals as per `Object.equals` (i.e `==`).